# How to publish Asp.Net WebService with debug information?

Tags: asp.net, debugging, publishing, remote-debugging

Starting with asp.net 2.0 the debug=true in the compilation section of the web.config file is deciding if the website/webservice will be compiled with debug information or not. But the compilation output is a lot of "gibberish" under the ASP.Net Temporary files. Only wiht publish i can get a clean output to be properly hosted under the WebServer. But there are no pdb files even if debug=true in the web.config.
 How can i possibly get the webservice to compile clean (as with publish) but with debug information as well? My purpose would be to publish the debug output on a remote production webserver and be able to debug into it.

Answer (score 1):

"Web Deployment Project" solved my problem. It plugs into Visual Studio and allows setting extra deployment options, including publishing with debug information.